# How to realize the excel function "offset" in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, offset

Does any one know how to realize the excel function "offset" in r?

It is easy to do this in excel, but it is so complicated to do this in r.

I attach the data and result here. What I want to do is extract the population from `data2` basing on the age information of `data1`.

For example, for year 2008, children go to primary school when they are 6 years old, so the first row of the `result` data frame should be number of year 2008 with age 6, but in 2010, children go to school at age 7, so I need to tell R to look up the value of age 7 in year 2009 of `data2`.

Another thing is how to ask R to add up the population number in different ages.  In `result` data frame, for the row number of children who are in primary school", in year 2008, it should add up all the children number from age 6 to age (6+6), but in year 2010, it should add up all the children number from age 7 to age (7+5)..

Any one have idea how to fix this? I am helping the kids and it would be great if you can help me with this..

Thanks a lot.

```
data1 = data.frame(item = c("Age for primary school","Duration for primary school", "Duration for middle school", "duration for high school"), 
                  '2008' = c(6, 6, 4, 3),  
                  '2009' = c(6, 6, 4, 3), 
                  '2010' = c(7, 5, 4, 3),  
                  '2011' = c(7, 5, 4, 3)) 

data2 = data.frame('population by age' = seq(3, 24, by = 1), 
                   '2008' = c(145391,
                              140621,
                              136150,
                              131944,
                              127968,
                              124209,
                              120650,
                              117163,
                              113674,
                              110207,
                              106871,
                              103659,
                              100398,
                              97017,
                              93584,
                              90240,
                              86957,
                              83783,
                              80756,
                              77850,
                              75003,
                              72226
                   ),  
                    '2009' = c(148566,
                               143943,
                               139367,
                               135083,
                               131052,
                               127237,
                               123628,
                               120213,
                               116826,
                               113381,
                               109915,
                               106574,
                               103346,
                               100058,
                               96644,
                               93175,
                               89788,
                               86455,
                               83241,
                               80192,
                               77279,
                               74422
                    ), 
                   '2010' = c(152330,
                              147261,
                              142555,
                              138172,
                              134071,
                              130214,
                              126559,
                              123099,
                              119825,
                              116538,
                              113134,
                              109669,
                              106320,
                              103075,
                              99760,
                              96312,
                              92805,
                              89372,
                              85988,
                              82733,
                              79661,
                              76739
                   ),  
                   '2011' = c(156630,
                              151387,
                              146491,
                              141905,
                              137593,
                              133545,
                              129737,
                              126124,
                              122678,
                              119397,
                              116093,
                              112666,
                              109174,
                              105791,
                              102505,
                              99159,
                              95699,
                              92193,
                              88759,
                              85373,
                              82123,
                              79065
                   )) 

result <- data.frame(item = c("number of children with primary school entry age",
                       "number of children who are in primary school",
                       "numer of children who are in completing primarys school"),
                       #"number of children who are in middle school",
                       #"number of children who are completing middle school",
                       #"number of children who are in high school",
                       #"number of children who are completing high school"),
                       "2008" = c(131944,845815,110207),
                       "2009" = c(135083,867420,113381),
                       "2010" = c(134071,750306, 116538),
                       "2011" = c(137593,769074,119397)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

For the kids!

```
as.data.frame(
mapply(function(x,y) {
  c(y[x[1]-2],                       # first acceptable age
    sum(y[(x[1]-2):(x[1]-2+x[2])]),  # sum within range
    y[x[1]-2+x[2]])                  # last acceptable age
  },
  data1[-1],data2[-1])
)

#    X2008  X2009  X2010  X2011
# 1 131944 135083 134071 137593
# 2 845815 867420 750306 769074
# 3 110207 113381 116538 119397
```

Comment: You are amazing, how can I follow you